# shopify api billing address different from shipping address

Tags: php, api, shopify

I'm working with the shopifys api and I came across this problem, I know that shopify uses the billing address country to validate credit card transactions, so the billing address country must match the credit card issuer country like it is said in this shopify forum post https://ecommerce.shopify.com/c/payments-shipping-fulfilment/t/need-help-with-shipping-billing-address-at-checkout-263790 but my problem is that I found that i can't create an order is the shipping address country field differs from the credit card issuer country, the api returns error 422 unprocesable entity if I do so, here is and example call to the api.

```
{
    "referring_site": "customLaravelShop.dev",
    "customer": {
        "first_name":"victor",
        "last_name":"alvarez",
        "email":"example@gmail.com"
    },
    "billing_address": {
        "first_name":"victor",
        "last_name":"alvarez",
        "address1":"qwerty",
        "phone":"+5812345678",
        "city":"london",
        "country":"IRELAND", // THIS SHOULD BE THE SAME COUNTRY AS THE THE CREDIT CARD ISSUER
        "zip":"1111"
    },
    "shipping_address": {
        "first_name":"victor",
        "last_name":"alvarez",
        "address1":"qwerty",
        "phone":"+584123607361",
        "city":"london",
        "country":"ENGLAND", // HERE IT LOOKS LIKE THE SHIPPING ADDRESS COUNTRY SHOULD BE THE SAME AS THE CREDIT CARD ISSUER
        "zip":"1111"
    },
    "email":"example@gmail.com",
    "line_items":[
        {
            "variant_id":11111111,
            "quantity":"1",
            "requires_shipping":true,
            "variant_title":"Default Title",
            "grams":1000
        }
    ],
    "note_attributes":[
        {
            "name":"Apron Polka Dot Check",
            "value":"Default Title x 1"
        }
    ],
    "shipping_lines":[
        {
            "code":"Shipping required",
            "price":"6.50",
            "title":"Shipping info"
        }
    ],
    "total_weight":1000,
    "subtotal_pricce":19.99,
    "total_price":"26.49",
    "order_number":"EXAMPLE-REALEX-ORDER-NUMBER-1234",
    "payment_gateway_names":["realex"],
    "processing_method":"realex",
    "reference":"EXAMPLE-REALEX-ORDER-REFERENCE-1234",
    "financial_status":"paid",
    "send_receipt":false,
    "transactions":[
        {
            "kind":"sale",
            "status":"success",
            "amount":"26.49",
            "gateway":"realex"
        }
    ]
}
```

I'm not sure if I'm missing something, but I think that the shipping address country field should not be related to the credit card issuer country, I can understand that the billing address country must match the credit card issuer country but billing and shipping are two very different things and sould not be related in this manner to each other

Comment: That's strange. Does it work when `IRELAND` is used instead of `ENGLAND`?

Comment: Yes thats the problem it works only when Ireland is set as a shipping country, mmm to be more precise, it only works when the credit card issuer country is the same as the shipping and billing addresses countries

Comment: Seems to be a bug. Post on Shopify forums and contact their support.